# Upper Bound of generic class and wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, super

```
class Gen <T super Number>           // 1 // IS NOT ALLOWED

void Demo( Gen <? super Number> ob)  // 2 // IS ALLOWED // Gen is a generic class
```

Why the first statement results in a compile time error and the second statement works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is a generic type. The second example is a parameterized type. They are different things.

- A generic type is a definition of a type that is parameterized over types. It can be invoked by providing type arguments to those type parameters.
- A parameterized type is an invocation of a generic type with type arguments, whether those type arguments are types or a wildcard.

A lower bound of a generic type's type parameter can't be of any use <sup>†</sup>. It isn't, therefore "a thing" in Java.

However the second example means: "any parameterisation of the type `Gen<T>`, where the type argument is a supertype of Number". It is useful as it allows polymorpyhism of generic types.

<sup>†</sup> They could actually be of limited use by providing ["restricted instantiation"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107), but weren't considered useful enough to be allowed.

Comment: `It is useful as it allows polymorpyhism of generic types`, is there any other use of the parameterized type?

Comment: @kevingomes. Wildcard parameterized types are all about polymorphism. `Gen<Object>` is not assignment compatible with `Gen<Number>`, but `Gen<?>` is. Bounding those wildcards with upper/lower bounds allows you to restrict the polymorphic set, which is useful as it creates the ability to have in/out parameters.